# Width of child vertical layout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a `HorizontalLayout` (let's call it *parent*). Inside this I have two `VerticalLayout`s (left's call them *left* and *right*).

*Left* contains just some text, *right* contains a lot of elements.

*Parent* has a width of 100% so it takes the full browser width:

`parent.setWidth("100%");`

*Left* should take just as much space as it needs, *right* should take all other space.

How can I do so? I tried all variations described [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.settings.html) and [there](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html) without success. I tried to:

- `left.setWidthUndefined();`
- `right.setWidth("100%");`
- `left.setWidth("150px");`
- `left.setWidth("30%");` together with `right.setWidth("70%");`

Nothing had an effect.

**Updated source code:**

```
HorizontalLayout parent = new HorizontalLayout();
parent.setCaption("Parent");

VerticalLayout left = new VerticalLayout();
left.setCaption("Left");

VerticalLayout right = new VerticalLayout();
right.setCaption("Right");

parent.addComponent(left);
parent.addComponent(right);
parent.setWidth("100%");
right.setWidth("100%");
parent.setExpandRatio(right, 1.0f);

setCompositionRoot(parent);
```

Comment: the 2 panels are visible in your browser if you check them with the inspector ? try to add height also

Comment: They aren't panels but layouts. Which inspector? Which height should I add? The height is quite variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick test, and the following seems to work:

```
...
left.setSizeUndefined();
parent.setWidth("100%");
parent.setExpandRatio(right, 1);
...
```

[image: screenshot]

This is the full code of the test application (without imports):

```
@Theme("reindeer")
public class ForumUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ForumUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    public static class SomeComponent extends CustomComponent {
        public SomeComponent() {
            HorizontalLayout parent = new HorizontalLayout();
            parent.setCaption("Parent");
            parent.addStyleName("v-ddwrapper-over");

            VerticalLayout left = new VerticalLayout();
            left.setCaption("Left");
            left.addStyleName("v-ddwrapper-over");

            VerticalLayout right = new VerticalLayout();
            right.setCaption("Right");
            right.addStyleName("v-ddwrapper-over");

            parent.addComponent(left);
            parent.addComponent(right);

            left.setSizeUndefined();
            parent.setWidth("100%");
            parent.setExpandRatio(right, 1);

            setCompositionRoot(parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new SomeComponent());
    }

}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html#layout.orderedlayout.sizing) for the space "distribution" of the `HorizontalLayout` component.

The key to solve your problem is to tell the `HorizontalLayout` component how to expand it's childrens via the `layout.setExpandRatio(leftComponent, 1.0f);` method.

Comment: I tried this before, but in a wrong place. Using your suggestion the right `VerticalLayout` is still not expanded to the full size. Do I have to set the width of parent to 100%?

Comment: Yes, your child components need to take all allowd size, to your children must have a width of 100%

Comment: I now have: `parent.setExpandRatio(left, 1.0f);` and `right.setWidth("100%");`. Still no success.

Comment: @mosquito87 you need `parent.setExpandRatio(**right**, 1)` if you want to have the `right` component to use all space.  also make sure, that all parents of parent have 100% width.

Comment: Doing so, the left part isn't shown anymore. I've posted my "simplified" source code in my question.